# What is meant by Karika bhasya?

Tags: scripture, terminology

What is meaning of Karika bhasya(commentarary)? How is it different from normal bhasyas?

What are examples of few Karika bhasyas apart from Gaudapada Karika bhasya on Mandukya upanishad?

Comment: Arthaprakaasika Kaarika.So Karika is the text of a doctrine or 'Satra'.. bhasya is its commentary.

Comment: This is the excellent question. Bravo.

Comment: Example in agamas we have spanda kaarika. Pratyabhijna karika etc and commentaries on it

Answer (score 1):

Karika bhasya means versified commentaries. Commentary is written in the form of verses.

Normal bhasya contains prose mainly.

Examples of Karika bhasyas:

Madhvacarya has two versified commentaries on the Brahma-sutras.
 1. In the Anubhasya, he summarized each of the four chapters in seven
    verses.
 2. In the Anuvyakhyana, he commented on most of the text in 1,920
    verses, yet he skipped many sutras.

Brahma Sutra Karika Bhasya by Baladeva Vidyabhusana. He explains all the 552 sutras in
 750 verses, most of them in anustup (32 syllables). Some aphorisms are glossed with a 
 quarter of a verse (pada), while others are more elaborately commented in several verses.

[Reference](https://bkdemian.blogspot.com/2017/11/baladeva-vidyabhusanas-karika-bhasya.html)